# Connecting to CouchBase with ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, couchdb

I am trying to load a Shapefile to CouchBase (version: 2.5.0 DEV edition, installed on Ubuntu), but with no success.

According to [this](http://www.gdal.org/drv_couchdb.html) documentation it is possible like this:

> ogr2ogr -f couchdb
> "couchdb:http://some_account.some_couchdb_server.com" shapefile.shp

so I tried like this:

> ogr2ogr -f couchdb `"couchdb:http://localhost:8092"` shapefile.shp

or

> ogr2ogr -f couchdb `"couchdb:http://localhost:8092/osm"` shapefile.shp

(where osm is an existing databucket)
and also with permissions:

> ogr2ogr -lco UPDATE_PERMISSIONS=ALL -f couchdb
> > `couchdb:http://localhost:8092` shapefile.shp

then I tried simply to connect:

> ogrinfo -ro `"couchdb:http://localhost:8092"`

which gives me the error:

> FAILURE:  Unable to open datasource `'couchdb:http://localhost:8092'`
> with the following drivers. [list of drivers including couchdb]

I also tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and also with port 8091 (and every combination of these).

Can anyone verify that the couchdb ogr2ogr driver is working and, if yes, what am I doing wrong?

Maybe the problem is that it is CouchBase instead of CouchDB.

My GDAL version is 2.0.0dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase is not Apache CouchDB compatible, hence the OGR driver doesn't work. AFAIK there's currently no OGR driver for Couchbase.